# How to copy a list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the following Groovy list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
println(l)
```

Which gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now I want to create a copy of this list:

```
println(l*.collect())
```

But this gives me the following:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Apparently I got a list of lists.
How can I create a list of the same objects as in the original list?

Comment: *. applies the method to each member of the list and returns a list of those modified elements, I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are using the spread operator (`*`), which is making a list out of each element. Remove that:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
println list1

list2 = list1.collect()
assert list2 == [1, 2, 3]
```

[Check out the doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28%29) for more info on that method.

Answer (score 26):

```
def list = [1, 2, 4]

//by value
def clonedList = list.clone() //or list.collect()
assert clonedList == list
assert !clonedList.is(list) //Reference inequality

list.pop() //modify list

assert clonedList == [1, 2, 4]
assert list == [1, 2]

//by reference
def anotherList = list
assert anotherList == [1, 2]
assert anotherList.is(list) //Reference equality

list.pop() //modify again

assert list == [1]
assert anotherList == [1]
```

Run it [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/2705002).

Comment: not just the most thorough answer, but the the simplest: clone a list with list.cone()

Comment: props for including the check that the cloned copy is unique from the original

Comment: only problem is if original list is immutable, then the clone is also immutable.

Comment: I got java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException when using clone(). Collect() worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
println list1

list2 = list1.collect{it}
assert list2 == [1, 2, 3]
```